# Importing .txt file with metadata before and after table into R

Tags: r

I am trying to import a .txt file into R, but am having some difficulty. My file has metadata in the file, before and after the actual data table. How do I tell the read.table() function to account for this? I've experimented with the skip parameter, but am not successful. If anyone could point me in the direction of a good resource, that would be great! I'm not getting there from the documentation alone.

Here is a Google Drive link to my .txt file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VG3fBso0s15NGeHnN32CK68bylxrB06t/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Show what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- read.table('hackr.txt',header = T, sep =';', skip=22, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# Optional: cn   <- colnames(data)

tmp <- as.data.frame(stringr::str_split_fixed(data[,1], "\t",n=Inf))[2:nrow(data),]
```

I can also clean up (remove) some junk columns for you:

```
for (f in names(tmp)) {
  if (length(unique(tmp[[f]])) == 1) {
    cat(f, "is constant. I am deleting it.\n"); tmp[[f]] <- NULL
}}
```

> ```
> head(tmp)
>     V1           V2         V3           V4       V5       V6         V7          V8          V9         V10      V11
>     2018-05-28   20:38:34   00:00:29.9   32.1     32.1     -.-        -.-         -.-         -.-                 
>     2018-05-28   20:38:34   00:00:29.8   32.7     32.4     -.-        -.-         -.-         -.-                 
>     2018-05-28   20:38:34   00:00:29.7   31.9     32.2     -.-        -.-         -.-         -.-                 
>     2018-05-28   20:38:34   00:00:29.6   34.9     33.1     -.-        -.-         -.-         -.-                 
>     2018-05-28   20:38:34   00:00:29.5   70.6     63.6     -.-        -.-         -.-         -.-                 
>     2018-05-28   20:38:34   00:00:29.4   70.4     65.7     -.-        -.-         -.-         -.-
> ```

If you want to keep the original headers just run the optional (commented) line as well and parse them with the same type of logic. They have a different delimiter than the rest of your table.